# How I can redirect to first child component vue router

Tags: redirect, vue.js, vue-router

I'm working on Vue Router. I have a problem. I wan't to redirect to first child component `(SettingProfile)` when I access in parent component `(settings)`.

Expect url: `localhost:8080/settings` --> `localhost:8080/settings/profile`

This is my router:

```
{
    name: 'settings',
    path: '/settings',
    component: () => import('./views/settings.vue'),
    children: [
    {
        path: 'profile',
        name: 'SettingProfile',
        component: () => import('./components/settings/profile.vue')
    },

    {
        path: 'account',
        name: 'account',
        component: () => import('./components/settings/account.vue')
    }
    ]
},
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add a redirect config, like:

```
{ path: '/settings', redirect: '/profile' }
```

It can be done using names as well. For more info, see the [docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/redirect-and-alias.html#redirect).

Comment: Oh, greate. That was my mistake, some how I was ignore this section on the docs. Thanks you for your assist. <3

Comment: Glad to help you!

Comment: Does it have to be a child route itself? In my case it´s not redirecting. The only thing that works for me(but only if I refresh the page) is {path: '', name: 'my-redirect'} as a child route

Answer (score 5):

This should work.

```
{
  path: '/parent-path',
  name: 'parent',
  component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "parent" */ '../views/Parent.vue'),
  redirect: { name: 'children' },
  children: [
    {
      path: 'child-path',
      name: 'children',
      component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "tasks" */ '../views/Child.vue'),
    },
  ]
}
```

Tested and this will auto redirect to `/parent-path/child-path`